# Python modules and global variables

Tags: python

There are many posts with a similar title, but none of them answer my question.

I have a code which does some analysis on a function. The definition of the function is in a module, say `definition.py`. Let's say the contents is

```
# module definition.py
def f(x):
   return x**2
```

All the functions that are used to perform the analysis are placed in a different module, say `analysis.py`

```
# module analysis.py
def factor2(x):
   return 2*f(x)
```

I would like the main code to look something like this

```
# main.py
from definition import *
from analysis import *

print( factor2(3.0) )
```

and expect to see the outcome '18.0'.

Notice, that I don't want to specify the function `f` explicitly in the definition of `factor2`. This does not work. The compiler says that name `f` is not defined.

I could define the function factor2 as `factor2(f,x)` and then pass the argument `f`. But this is exactly what I am trying to avoid. This is because the purpose of the whole code is to work only on `f` and it is tedious to write that f over and over again. Plus it makes the code much longer (if there are many such f's and many analysis functions).

Is there a way how to pass the definition of `f` from `definition.py` into `analysis.py`?

Importing `definition.py` from within `analysis.py` is no good as I want to be able to change the definition of `f` by importing a different module, say `definition2.py`, without touching the `analysis.py` module any more.

Comment: No, Python use *lexical scope*, you are basically asking for dynamic scope. The best way would be to pass the function as an argument. You can simply partially apply `f` once and then work with that. So `factor2f = lambda x: factor2(func, x)` The other alternative is to use a class where you provide `f` to the constructor and use it as an instance attribute.

Comment: Note, starred imports are considered bad.

Comment: Thanks @juanpa.arrivillaga, I was afraid that this is the case. Probably I will have to go with a solution like yours. Although it is not optimal, as in case there are many functions of the type 'factor2', then I have to write the whole litany of them.

Comment: @juanpa Why do you use a lambda instead of `functools.partial`? The lambda's repr is not useful, but a partial's is.

Comment: @wjandrea just an example.

Comment: `import definition, analysis; analysis.f = definition.f` perhaps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be better to use a partial, as [juanpa.arrivillaga](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5014455/juanpa-arrivillaga) explained in [a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62349295/python-modules-and-global-variables/62349664#comment110270549_62349295):

> Python [uses] *lexical* scope, you are basically asking for *dynamic* scope. The best way would be to pass the function as an argument. You can simply partially apply `f` once and then work with that.

For example:

```
from functools import partial
from definition import f

def actor2(function, x):  # "factor" without the "f" ;)
    return 2*function(x)

factor2 = partial(actor2, f)
```

```
>>> factor2(3)
18
>>> factor2  # Also here's the repr, which you wouldn't get if you used a lambda
functools.partial(<function actor2 at 0x...>, <function f at 0x...>)
```

---

juanpa also said:

> The other alternative is to use a class where you provide `f` to the constructor and use it as an instance attribute.

If you're going to do more with the class, this is a great option. Otherwise it's overkill, like [Jack Diederich said](https://youtu.be/o9pEzgHorH0?t=180):

> The signature of "this shouldn't be a class" is that it has two methods, one of which is `__init__`. [...] If you find that you're always passing the same first argument to that function, hey, standard library has a thing for that, `functools.partial`.

Comment: Thanks, @wjandrea. Eventually it looks like the best working implementation for me is to use classes. I was hoping for a quick fix, but well... Thanks for other commenters too.